# " Cannot read property 'userData' of undefined " this error is popping while I am doing user authentication using aungular 8 anf firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2, angular8

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthenticationService {
  userData: Observable<firebase.User>;
  constructor(private angularFireAuth: AngularFireAuth) { 
    this.userData = angularFireAuth.authState;
  }
  /* Sign Up */
  SignUp(email: string, password: string) {
    this.angularFireAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
    .then(res => { console.log('You are successfully signed up!', res);
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log('Something is wrong:', error.message);
    });
  } 
  /* Sign In */
  SignIn(email: string, password:string) {
    this.angularFireAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(res => {
      console.log('You are successfully logged in!');
    }).catch(err => {`enter code here`
      console.log('Something is wrong!', err.message);
    });
  }

  /* Sign Out */
  SignOut() {
    this.angularFireAuth.auth.signOut();
  }
}
```

The userData variable cannot be read during the authentication process of user. The above code is for web made using angular 8 and firebase .

Answer (score 0):

Could please you check again

```
app.module.ts
```

inside the code is there ...

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    // ...
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),// <<<<<------
    AngularFireAuthModule // <<<<<<-------------
  ],
  providers: [AuthService],// <<<<<----------------
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Comment: Yes, I have embedded this components inside the app.module.ts file